# How to create a single page vertical scrolling site in Joomla

Tags: joomla, scroll

I can create a standard Joomla template in my sleep, but recently I had a client come to me who wants a vertically scrolling, single page site. I whipped up an HTML/CSS mockup that functions beautifully but I have a question re: converting it to a Joomla template:

Do I just create a single article in Joomla that contains all of the content for the single page, and then create menu items that link to the section divs?

Many thanks,

Cynthia

Comment: I would ask this on the joomla.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: check this out http://www.fasterjoomla.com/extensions/88-jparallax-an-easy-parallax-navigation-for-joomla (see the link at the end of the page) it's still in beta but if you're interested contact me and I'll share it, it reads content for each block from modules, articles or custom content

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you want to create?

Answer (score 0):

yes I think that good , also you can make all items in "index.php" in template folder and make menu items link to divs by "#" plus ID .
you can add all items you want as module and you can use component in modules plugin lik :
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/embed-a-include/18121

Hope that help you

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better to insert the content via creating a bespoke module or component - putting code in the WYSIWYG area kind of defeats the point of using a CMS at all - someone with no coding skills has to be able to update the site and not accidentally delete the layout.

I'd perhaps question why it needs it to be in Joomla at all, though.  It doesn't sound like it will be benefiting from many of its features.